# wait() cannot find previously triggered alias route

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, cypress

Using Cypress js, I have creating end to end tests for a website, and fired the tests in powershell. For some lack of knowledge, aliased routes are not as I expected them to be, when using the `wait()` function.

**core of cypress test issue:**

```
cy.route("http://localhost:8000/admin/portfolio/putstrategy")
    .as("updatestrategy")

cy.get("button")
    .contains("Upload")
    .click()

cy.wait("@updatestrategy")
```

**logs:**

[image]

I am expecting `wait()` to match on the request initiated by the button click. What I am getting now is a successful request response, seemingly all before the test can catch up.

[**From the docs:**](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wait.html#Alias)

`Each time we use cy.wait() for an alias, Cypress waits for the next nth matching request.`

My understanding of this quote is that `wait()` will match on the request, who's execution order number matches the waits execution order number, relative to the same address.

Requests can time out and responses can timeout. With this scenario, no request is found matching the wait's number.

How can I use Cypress to wait on a programmatically invoked request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your route should point to just the path, not the full URL.  Try changing it to `cy.route("/admin/portfolio/putstrategy").as("updatetrategy")`

I'm assuming it's just a snippet from your test, but if you don't have `cy.server()` before you call into `cy.route()`, you'll need to add that as well.

Answer (score 1):

^^ like he said but it since its a POST request. It should look like this

```
cy.route("POST", "/admin/portfolio/putstrategy").as("updatetrategy")
```